# Is there a way to check CMakeLists files for unused packages?

Tags: c++, cmake

I recently inherited a c++ project which uses `cmake`.  I spent quite some time figuring out how to get the right version of a library which was required by a `CMakeLists.txt` file's `find_package` call, only to find out that the package is not actually used by the code.  I know there are all sorts of reasons this shouldn't happen (better documentation, ask before doing, etc), but it did spark a question: is there a standard way to detect unused packages like this in cmake?

I tried [`cmakelint`](https://github.com/cmake-lint/cmake-lint), but that doesn't seem to catch it.  Maybe it's not possible in an automated way?

Comment: Automatic checking is often not possible. Some libraries don't have hard dependencies on those libraries and e.g. only offered additional optional features whether those libs are available or not. Sometimes the library is only used for backward compatibility for older c++ versions(e.g. some boost features). Sometimes the external dependency is only required if a certain template type is passed to a function of the project, ... . If the project has a full set of unit tests, then it would be possible through those to figure out if a dependencie is not required.

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot of sense.  Thanks!